Embedding magento page in Zendesk help center
I'd like to embed a basic Magento page into Zendesk help center. Zendesk allows the  tag to be used but Magento is passing an x-frame-options of SAMEORIGIN  that is blocking the embed from working.
I don't want to allow the whole of the Magento website to be embedded, only the specific basic page.
What is the best way to do this?
Web server is Nginx
Thanks in advance

You can do that in the configuration of the nginx server with the following code:
server {
    # Other server configurations...

    location /path/to/page {
        # Allow embedding only for this specific path
        add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://your-zendesk-domain.zendesk.com";
    }
    
    location / {
        # Set X-Frame-Options for the rest of the site
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}


Replace the URL with the correct ones to make this case work. Same can apply to CPS tags if required to make Magento work on the IFrame

This isn't working. The SAMEORIGIN header is still being written. The SAMEORIGIN header is written in several places in the nginx config file as well as from Magento

See this. You need to remove the headers from the response and add it again based on the rules. Also, make sure you are having your rule as the last step.
